# Removing a node from a binary search tree in Java

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I've implemented a binary search tree with nodes (represented as users) but I'm having trouble getting my `deFriend()` method to work. This method should delete a node from the tree whilst keeping the "rules" of a binary search tree - e.g. root bigger than left sub-tree, but smaller than right sub-tree.

I understand that when deleting a node from a binary search tree, I should consider 3 cases:
1 - when the node to delete has no children,
2 - when the node to delete has one child,
3 - when the node to delete has two children. can't figure this one out
My `deFriend()` method works for the first two cases but not for the last one. I even know what node I need to replace it with if it's the third case but I can't get it down with code. I can conceptualize it or draw it on paper, but I can't translate that to code. I've included links to the two classes that I think are necessary to fixing my problem. I'm convinced my problem lies between lines 111 and 114 of my `BinaryTree` class. Thanks in advance.

User class: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/732f02628f6edf622d88363b68cf22ee
BinaryTree class: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1be7b5577c959dc1bcf6c77474b11bce

Comment: We're not a debugging service.  You're throwing 400 lines of code at us and asking us to fix it.  That's not what StackOverflow is for.  If you can conceptualize it and draw it on paper, then please ask a question that shows us what your concept is, and shows us _just_ the code you're attempting to write, and then maybe we can help you.  We also don't like links to code.  Please post the code as part of the question, but not all 400 lines.

Answer (score 1):

When removing a node from a binary search tree it is mandatory to maintain the in-order sequence of the nodes. There are three possible cases to consider:

- if node has no children simply remove the node from the tree.
- if node has one child remove the node and replace it with its child.
- if node D has two children do not delete it. Instead, choose either its in-order predecessor node or its in-order successor node as replacement node E. Copy the user values of E to D. If E does not have a child simply remove E from its previous parent. If E has a child, say F, it is a right child. Replace E with F at E's parent.